# Tags not rendering in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, rendering

```js
const Albums = ({artist, album, textBarInput}) => {  

    let indexOfTheArtist = takeTheIndexOfTheArtist(artist);   // -1 means not found    |    >= 0   means found and return his position
    let artistAlbums =  bands[indexOfTheArtist].albums
            
    for(let i = 0; i < artistAlbums.length; i+=1){
        return(
             <Record spotifyLink={artistAlbums[i].spotifyLink} imageLink={artistAlbums[i].imageLink} title={artistAlbums[i].title} releaseDate={artistAlbums[i].releaseDate}></Record>
                );
    }
}


const Record = ({spotifyLink, imageLink, title, releaseDate}) => {
    return(
            <a href={spotifyLink} rel='noreferrer' target='_blank'><img src={imageLink} alt={title}></img></a>,
            <p>{title}</p>,
            <p>Release Date: {releaseDate}</p>
        );
}

export default Albums
```

Hi there,
I'm working on a personal project which is a music gallery using React. So I have two select options(one for artists and one for albums) and an input bar so that the user can type the artist that they want and get the albums of that band. I also have an array named bands in which each entrance is a dictionary with the artist name (artist) and also a dictionary with all of the albums of that band with data like release date, spotify link and an image source of the album cover. As you can see on my Albums component I receive as props the input from the user, but when I pass these values to the Record component the only thing that renders on the page is the release date paragraph. Am I missing something?

[image: this is the code]
[image: the console.log]

Comment: try `console.log(artistAlbums[i])` before the `return` in your `for` loop, and tell us what you got. Maybe you don't receive well the information, and the component can't render without it.

Comment: @BaptisteRieber I did what you suggested and  I found out that it's just passing the data of the 1st position of the albums dictionary, but the image link, spotify link and so on are ok. I don't understand why it doesn't show on the page.

Comment: then try replacing your for loop by the following code : `for(let album in artistsAlbums){
        return(
             <Record spotifyLink={album .spotifyLink} imageLink={album .imageLink} title={album .title} releaseDate={album .releaseDate}></Record>
                );
    }`

Comment: Now not even the release date prop is shown. I console.logged the artistsAlbums and the data is all there so the problem may be on the for loop right?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a screen shot of what you get with the console.log that I suggested you first ?

Comment: Done, I changed the code to the first suggestion. Notice that It's just one album shown, but that's just the first entrance of the array.

Answer (score 1):

i'm pretty sure that the problem is data not being updated correctly.
try adding a state that holds your current artist, and then for every record just pass the data from the state. something like this:

- add a state in your main component:
  `const [currentArtist, setCurrentArtist] = useState({});`
- use the `setCurrentArtist` after choosing the right artist,
- add record for each album like this:

```js
{currentArtist.albums.map((album) => <Record {...album} />)}
```

make sure the artist object in the state has keys with the props names. it should look like this:

```js
{ spotifyLink: '.../.../', imageLink: '.../.../', title: 'Song Title' ...}
```

by doing so, you can just spread the album item as a prop (example in code) and not needing to pass props one by one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked! I had to change a little thing but I got what I want.

Comment: np man, please upvote the answer so people will know it helped you

Comment: I tried but unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to do that, tho the vote has been recorded by Stack Overflow.